# how to check checkbox state in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I upgrade my jQuery library to 1.9.1 and have this code:

```
if (
    !($("#Days_Sat").attr("checked"))
    && !($("#Days_Sun").attr("checked"))
    && !($("#Days_Mon").attr("checked"))
    && !($("#Days_Tu").attr("checked"))
    && !($("#Days_We").attr("checked"))
    && !($("#Days_Tr").attr("checked"))
    && !($("#Days_Fr").attr("checked"))) {
         alert("pleas select day");
            }
```

but even i select day checkbox the alert shown!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check checkbox checked property using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/check-checkbox-checked-property-using-jquery)

Comment: This was VERY EASY  question , so u got 10 answers , You could google a little.

Comment: And what an odd choice of correct answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuery `is` method instead of `attr`.

[jQuery API link](http://api.jquery.com/is/).

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sx4wtkc0/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `is(':checked')` to know the checkbox state, this will return `true` if checkbox is checked otherwise `false`. see below code

```
if (!($("#Days_Sat").is(':checked'))
    && !($("#Days_Sun").is(':checked'))
    && !($("#Days_Mon").is(':checked'))
    && !($("#Days_Tu").is(':checked'))
    && !($("#Days_We").is(':checked'))
    && !($("#Days_Tr").is(':checked'))
    && !($("#Days_Fr").is(':checked'))) 
   {
      alert("pleas select day");
   }
```

If you have all your concerned checkbox `id` starting with `Days` then you can use **[jQuery start with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)** to get all checkbox with `id` starting from 'Days_' and get the length of object to find if none of them is selected. see below code

```
var checked = $('input[id^="Days_"]:checked').length;
if(checked==0)
  alert("pleas select day");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('##Days_Sun').is(':checked');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.is()` method with `:checked` selector. like this:

```
$("#Days_Fr").is(":checked")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would check if there is any ID starting with "Days_" that is checked. If not (!) the if clause will be thruthy.

```
if (!$("[id^='Days_']:checked").length) alert("pleas select day");
```

```js
$('button').click(function(){
    if (!$("[id^='Days_']:checked").length) alert('please choose a day...');
    else alert('cool...');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="Days_Sat" />
<input type="checkbox" id="Days_Sun" />
<input type="checkbox" id="Days_Mon" />
<input type="checkbox" id="Days_Tu" />
<input type="checkbox" id="Days_We" />
<input type="checkbox" id="Days_Tr" />
<input type="checkbox" id="Days_Fr" />
<button type="button">Test</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make your code easiers to read i would go for:

```
if ( $('#Days_Sat, #Days_Sun, #Days_Mon, #Days_Tu, #Days_We, #Days_Tr, #Days_Fr').filter(':checked').length != 1 )
{

}
```

Other than that: like the other people already answered: `.is(':checked')` is your solution here.

Answer (score 0):

Check like this

```
if(!$("[id^='Days_']").is(':checked')){

         alert("pleas select day");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('#your_id').is(':checked')` gives you either check box is checked or not.
It returns true if it is checked or false when not checked

```
  if($('#Days_Sat').is(':checked'))
    {
    do something...
    }
```

and you full code

```
if(!$('#Days_Sat').is(':checked')&&!$('#Days_Sun').is(':checked')&&!$('#Days_Mo').is(':checked')&&!$('#Days_Tu').is(':checked')&&!$('#Days_Th').is(':checked')&&!$('#Days_Fr').is(':checked'))
{
alert("pleas select day");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the jsfiddle here [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/buroj5wt/)

```
$(function(){

    $('#check').click(function(){
        if($("[id^='days_']:checked").length !=7 ){
        alert("Please select a day");}
        else{alert("works fine");}
    });

  });
```

This will popup the alert if any checkboxe is not clicked.

if you want that atleast one should be selected you can do

```
if($("[id^='days_']:checked").length !=0 )
```